# Splunk filter one search by another

Tags: filter, splunk

I have two searches that will return orderNumbers

search1
 index=main "Failed insert" | table orderNumber //returns small list

search2
 index=main "Successful insert" | table orderNumber //returns huge list

I want a list of "Failed insert" orderNumbers that have NOT had a "Successful insert" previously. How can I use the results of the second search to filter the results of the first search?

I tried:

index=main "Failed insert"
NOT [ index=main "Successful insert" | table orderNumber]
| dedup orderNumber
| table orderNumber

...but it returned orderNumbers that did have "Successful insert" events.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
index=main sourcetype=srctp orderNumber=* "failed insert" NOT
    [search index=main sourcetype=srctp orderNumber=* "successful insert"
    | stats count by orderNumber
    | fields - count ]
| stats count by orderNumber
| fields - count
```

First, `stats` is going to be a lot more performant than `dedup`

Second, so long as your "successful insert" search is 10k items or fewer, it should complete

If it's longer than 10k items, you may need to do something like this:

```
index=main sourcetype=srctp orderNumber=* ("failed insert" OR "successful insert")
| rex field=_raw "(?<insert>\w+ )insert"
| stats values(insert) as inserts by orderNumber
| search inserts="*failed*"
| where mvcount(inserts)<2
```

What this should do is extract the type of insert ("failed" or "successful") into a new field named `insert`

Then `stats values()` all of the insert types each `orderNumber` had

Then ensure we're only looking at `orderNumber` entries that have a "failed" insert

Then check to make sure there is only one entry in the `values()`'d field (ie there is no "successful" entry present

Comment: This ended up working for me:

`index=main  "failed insert"
| stats count by orderNumber
| eval previousSuccess=0
| table orderNumber previousSuccess
| join type=left orderNumber
[search index=main “successful insert” | eval previousSuccess=1 | table orderNumber previousSuccess]
| table orderNumber previousSuccess
| where previousSuccess=0`



*for some reason, I'm having trouble with the code block markdown. Sorry about that.